Consistency of a hypothesis test
I have given statistical model $((0,1)^n, \mathcal{B}(0,1)^n,\mathcal{P}_n)$, where $\mathcal{P}_n=\{ P_{\theta}^{\otimes n} \ |\ \theta \in (0, \infty) \}$ and each $P_{\theta}$ has density function $f_{\theta}(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}$, and $P_{\theta}^{\otimes n}$ denotes the product measure, while assuming independency. We want to test:
$$H: \theta \leq 1 \ ; \ K: \theta>1$$
using the test, $$\varphi_n(x)=\chi_{\{T_n(x)>-\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}\}}$$
where $T_n(x)=\sum_\limits{i=1}^nlog(x_i)$ and $\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-quantile of the $Erlang(n,1)$ distribution.
I am trying to show that $\varphi_n$ is a consistent test, so:
$$\lim_\limits{n \longrightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}_{\theta}(\varphi_n)=1, \ \theta >1$$
My Attempt goes as follows:
Firstly I showed that $Y_i:=-log(X_i) \sim Exp(\theta), \ X_i \sim P_{\theta}$, then we know $\sum_\limits{i=1}^n Y_i \sim Erlang(n,\theta)$, or  $\sum_\limits{i=1}^n \theta Y_i \sim Erlang(n,1)$, since $\theta Y_i \sim Exp(1) $, using the assumed independency.
So we end up with $-\theta \ T_n(X) \sim Erlang(n,1) $, so if we denote $\gamma_{n,1}(x)$ as the distribution function of the $Erlang(n,1)$ distribution, we get following:
$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta}(\varphi_n)=P_{\theta}(T_n(X)>-\gamma_{n,1,\alpha})=P(-\theta T_n(X)<\theta \ \gamma_{n,1,\alpha})=\gamma_{n,1}(\theta \ \gamma_{n,1,\alpha})$$
It is suggested to show that  $\lim_\limits{n \longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}}{n}=1$, which I didn't quite manage to show, but assuming I would show it, we can now use that $\lim_\limits{n \longrightarrow\infty}\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}= \infty$, which I assume implies that
$$\lim_\limits{n \longrightarrow\infty}\gamma_{n,1}(\theta \ \gamma_{n,1,\alpha})=1$$
using that $\gamma_{n,1}$ is a distribution function. But I am not quite sure how to rigorously argue that this holds.
So my Question lies within, how to actually show, that $\lim_\limits{n \longrightarrow\infty}\frac{\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}}{n}=1$ and how to use this in showing $\lim_\limits{n \longrightarrow\infty}\gamma_{n,1}(\theta \ \gamma_{n,1,\alpha})=1$.
Any help is appreciated.

What is your definition of $\alpha$-quantile (because I call this the $(1-\alpha)$th quantile)?

@StubbornAtom, for a distribution function $F$, the $\alpha$-quantile is $F^{-1}(\alpha):=inf{t\in \mathbb{R} \ | \ F(t) \geq \alpha }, \ \alpha \in (0,1)$.

You can use the asymptotic distribution of $T_n$, obtained from the central limit theorem:
$$\frac{-\theta T_n-n}{\sqrt n} \stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,1).$$
Since $-\theta T_n$ has a Gamma distribution with $(1-\alpha)$th quantile $\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}$, this quantile when similarly centred and scaled will converge to the corresponding quantile of standard normal distribution:
$$\frac{\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}-n}{\sqrt n}\longrightarrow z_{\alpha}.$$
Now,
\begin{align}
P_{\theta}(T_n>-\gamma_{n,1,\alpha})&=P_{\theta}\left(-\theta T_n< \theta \gamma_{n,1,\alpha}\right)
\\&=P_{\theta}\left(\frac{-\theta T_n-n}{\sqrt n}< \theta\left(\frac{\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}-n}{\sqrt n}\right)+\sqrt n(\theta-1)\right).
\end{align}
Let $x_n=\theta\left(\frac{\gamma_{n,1,\alpha}-n}{\sqrt n}\right)+\sqrt n(\theta-1)$, so that (since $\theta>1$) $x_n\to \infty$.
Now it can be argued using Polya's theorem that for $\theta>1$,
$$P_{\theta}\left(\frac{-\theta T_n-n}{\sqrt n}< x_n\right) - \Phi(x_n) \longrightarrow 0,$$
where $$\Phi(x_n) \longrightarrow \Phi(\infty)=1,$$
from which the desired result follows.
